# Page load happens before data returned via xhr in angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ajax, xmlhttprequest

We are facing a challenge in loading document urls fetched from S3 and displaying thumb images on the dashboard tab page.

```
  /***fetch docs **push success confirm***/
    $scope.getdocuments = function(){
        DDListDataService.getDocumentTypes().then(function(docs){
            $scope.docTypes = docs.data;
        });

        userService.fetchUserDocs($scope.user.customerId,$scope.user.entityType).then(function(userDocs){ 

            //console.log("result--"+userDocs);

            angular.forEach(userDocs, function(object , key){
                console.log(object);
                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                var blob;
                xhr.open('GET', object.documents[0].documentUrl);
                //var file = common.base64ToBlob(object.d, true);
                xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';

                xhr.onload = function(e) {

                    //var file = remoteToBlob(object.documents[0].documentUrl);
                    //var file = common.base64ToBlob(object.documents[0].document, 'image/jpg');
                    /*file.lastModifiedDate = new Date();
                    file.name = "";*/

                    var file = new Blob([this.response], {type: 'image/jpg'});
                    //rest of the code that uses the blob goes here

                    file.lastModifiedDate = new Date();
                    file.name = "";

                    //setTimeout(function(){console.log(file)},1000);

                    var options = {
                            customerId : $scope.user.customerId,
                            customerType : $scope.user.entityType,
                            docTypeName : object.key.documentName,
                            documentName : object.key.documentNameId,
                            documentVersion : object.key.documentVersion,
                            documentUID : object.doccumentUID,
                            //requestedBy : $scope.user.customerType,
                            requestedBy : LocalService.get('userType'),
                            requestedById : $scope.user.customerId

                    }

                    var fileItem = new FileUploader.FileItem($scope.uploader,file,options);
                    fileItem.progress = 100;
                    fileItem.isUploaded = true;
                    fileItem.isSuccess = true;

                    /*file.customerId = $scope.user.customerId;
                    file.customerType =$scope.user.entityType;
                    file.documentName = object.key.documentNameId;
                    file.documentVersion =object.key.documentVersion;
                    file.documentUID = object.doccumentUID;
                    file.requestedBy = $scope.user.customerId;
                    file.requestedById = $scope.user.customerId;*/

                    $scope.uploader.queue.push(fileItem);
                    console.log(fileItem);
                };
                xhr.send();
            });
        });
        //$scope.uploader.formData=[{"user":angular.json($scope.user)}];
        $scope.uploader.queue.length = 0;
        }
```

After the `xhr.send()` is executed the page load happens but the data is still not ready and it gives undefined file object as the data is not returned in the mean time. How can we hault the load till the data is returned? The onload I believe has a callback which should carry out the function.Correct me if wrong.
How can this be handled?
The html to display the image is

```
   <div ng-show="uploader.isHTML5" ng-thumb="{ file: item._file, height: 100 ,stream:item._file}"></div>
```

Comment: why aren't you using the angular ajax syntax?

Comment: New to angular.Could you just explain how it would work in angular and would it solve the issue we are facing? @madalinivascu

Comment: you should use **$http** service provided by angular [see an example here](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07).

Comment: @oliv37 Could you suggest a correction to the current code? I would like to get the current thing working and then move towards writing a service for this.

Answer (score 0):

The time it takes for the page to load is independent of the time it takes for your xhr request to complete.

So, create a window.load function that calls another function, and put what you need after the xhr request inside that other function like this:

```
$(window.load(function (){
afterXHRLoad(); //This calls the afterXHRLoad function after the page loads
});

function afterXHRLoad(){
if($.active == 0)
{
//code needed here;
}
else
{
setTimeout(afterXHRLoad, 1000); //recursively call the function after 1 second
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply @Mr. Whales will try it out and let you know.